# How to use the django rest-auth views with custom html templates instead of browserable APIs

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-rest-auth

I am using django `rest-auth` and `allauth` for a login/logout and registration on my website. These are very easy to use and work well. however, the browseable APIs are ugly for production. I want to fully customize my login view but still have the underlying rest-auth logic in place.

I was not able to find helpful tutorials on how to do this. I found this: https://wsvincent.com/django-user-authentication-tutorial-login-and-logout/ which is exactly what I want to do but with `rest-auth` rather than the build-in user authentication system that django offers.

How can I do this? is there a default `.html` files that I can override?

### details

this is my app's `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

the above have default views, I would like to overwrite their templates.

### update

the way I got this to work is to overrode the LoginView in rest-auth with the following:

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, "api/test_template.html")
```

but now in `test_template.html` how do I make input fields that feed to the same inputs of `rest-auth login` automatically?

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/renderers.py#L240 HTMLFormRenderer, your form is rendered based on this class's output. Is this the behavior you want?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using DRF we can safely assume that you have serializers established for your views (**If you don't then you should**).

If you have then you can follow the [HTML & Forms](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#rendering-forms) part of the documentation:

> Serializers may be rendered as forms by using the `render_form` template tag and including the serializer instance as context to the template.
>
> The following view demonstrates an example of using a serializer in a template for viewing and updating a model instance:
>
> **views.py:**
>
> ```
> from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
> from my_project.example.models import Profile
> from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer
> from rest_framework.views import APIView
>
>
> class ProfileDetail(APIView):
>     renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
>     template_name = 'profile_detail.html'
>
>     def get(self, request, pk):
>         profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=pk)
>         serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile)
>         return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'profile': profile})
>
>     def post(self, request, pk):
>         profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=pk)
>         serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile, data=request.data)
>         if not serializer.is_valid():
>             return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'profile': profile})
>         serializer.save()
>         return redirect('profile-list')
> ```
>
> **profile_detail.html:**
>
> ```
> {% load rest_framework %}
>
> <html><body>
>
> <h1>Profile - {{ profile.name }}</h1>
>
> <form action="{% url 'profile-detail' pk=profile.pk %}" method="POST">
>     {% csrf_token %}
>     {% render_form serializer %}
>     <input type="submit" value="Save">
> </form>
>
> </body></html>
> ```

You can probably directly use or override the [`rest-auth`'s `LoginSerializer`](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/serializers.py#L19) and have a look on how the [`LoginView`](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/views.py#L33) that your `CustomLoginView` class inherits from.

Answer (score 0):

There is no template in your app, there's just APIs and since you are using DRF, it shows you a generated page that is used to document your APIs. So in my opinion you don't need to override anything, what you need to do is that use a front-end framework (like Angular and reactjs) and in the front-end pages, call those APIs provided by `rest_auth`.

Comment: Yes we are using a front end framework, but authentication rules are too strict how can I change them?

Comment: @juanIsaza some of `django-rest-auth` rules are configurable. It depends on what you want to change? check its documentation and if you didn't find anything useful I recommend you to check other packages. Here's some useful packages you can find: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#third-party-packages